# LP Constraints for Bridgeless Cactus Graphs

Tags: graph-theory, linear-programming, special-graphs

When trying to determine the optimal bridgeless spanning [cactus graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cactus_graph) of a weighted, symmetric graph, I got stuck.

What I do not know how to capture, is

- the variable number and sizes of the cycles
- the pairs of cycles that share a vertex, i.e. the "cycle adjacency"
- the set of cycles that share a specific vertex, i.e. the "cycle degree" of a vertex.

What can easily be concluded, is that the set of constraints must contain the ones for a spanning tree and thus certain subtour elmination constraints.

What also can easily be concluded, is that the vertex degrees must be even.

> **Questions:**
>
> - what are the LP constraints, that guarantee that the solution is a connected graph, of which each edge belongs to exactly one cycle, while not imposing non-trivial restrictions on the number of cycles, i.e. it allows for any number of cycles between $1$ and $\frac{n-1}{2}$?
> - do the corners of the polytope have integer coordinates?

Comment: Do you have any reason to believe that these properties can be expressed as an LP?

Comment: @GordonRoyle it is more a hope for existence of an LP formulation, which is backed up by the great variety of problems that admit an LP formulation.

Comment: [Spanning cactus of a graph: Existence, extension, optimization, and approximation](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0166218X1200306X) provides some hardness results for the Minimum Spanning Cactus Problem